# Workflow condition liferay 7.1 form

Tags: workflow, liferay-7.1

I have a problem with the Workflow of liferay 7.1.

I have created a form for the request of vacation and permissions. Also, I have created some roles which I have assigned to specific users.

I wish the request would achieve to a specified role (I thought an if or switch) and the notification to the users with another role.

I would like to work with the IDs because every role has its ID so I can manage them easier.

Does anyone know how to make this task and this situation?

For example es. role HR (id 33377), role Developer (id 33388).